# Should images be cached or downloaded? What's the proper way?

Tags: android, caching

A little background: The main page contains about 25 thumbnail images displayed in a recycle view. I receive a JSON response from an API containing the urls for those images alongside other data.

I save the JSON string in an objectBox database instance and use `GSON.fromJSON` to create the actual objects when I need to display them. Btw I use the MVVM pattern.

Now there are three scenarios I would like to consider:

1) when changing activities any currently not displayed activity can be deleted at any point by the os without warning and the images with it. Should I cache the images (where? in memory (don't want to waste it) or storage?) or should I just download them again when user returns to the main activity? Seems to me like downloading the images every time user switches the activities would be quite demanding.

2) when user switches off the application entirely and launches it again everything not saved on disk will be wiped off. I would be ok to download the images in this case since it's just one time process and the database will probably need bringing up to date anyway.

3) finally when the phone is not connected to internet the app should display some images even though they might not be current.

So my question is, how should images be cached in scenario like this one and what's the right way to do it?

Can I cache images in objectBox directly or would i be better off with SQLite? Or should i use some other library like Picasso for caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally yes, images should be cached in at least memory, and depending on your app (how likely is it to be reused,etc) in memory and storage.  If you want to support your 3rd point (displaying when offline), you need to do storage caching, and memory caching is optional but probably a good idea.

What library (or if you use a library, I've had good reasons to roll my own on a few times) to use is way off topic for this site, as its mainly opinion.  And we'd need lots of specific knowledge of your usecase to advise one over the other.

Comment: Thank you, could I use objectBox for storage caching? I would like to keep all the data in one place rather than cache the images 'somewhere' in internal storage, completely unrelated to the database.

Comment: Images in a db are a highly contentious issue. My own opinion is never do that, but it would be ok to store the location of the file on storage in the db

Comment: Brilliant, that's what i wanted to know. How come it's contentious? Wouldn't be ok to convert an image into a bitmap object and store it in objectBox like any other object?

Comment: Because it isn't searchable, and bloats the db possibly impacting performance. It also increases load in the db (an expensive, difficult to scale resource) compared to a storage box (easy to scale). Of course most of the arguments around that are for remote dbs